# Возможно ли при выполнении функции вернуть имя переменной к которой эта функция присвоена? (python)

Tags: python

Нужно получить имя переменной (в функции) к которой присвоена функция.

```
a, b = 0, 1

def func():
    print('Имя переменной')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = func() # Должно вывести а
    b = func() # Должно вывести b
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это возможно. Более того - если написать вызов нескольких функций справа от присваивания и скажем сложить их результаты, то они друг о друге тоже ничего знать не будут, все они выполняются независимо друг от друга.

Comment: В таком виде это не возможно. Внутри классов дескрипторы данных могут получить имя, куда они присвоены, но обычные функции - нет.

Comment: В момент вычисления выражения `func()` его результат еще никуда не присвоен. поэтому - невозможно.

Answer (score -1):

```
a, b = 0, 1
def func(int):
    print(int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(a)
    func(b)
```

Я точно не понял, что тебе нужно, но вроде это выглядит так, если это не то, то пожалуйста, объясни поподробней задачу.
Или вот ещё вариант:

```
a, b = 0, 1
def func(int):
    print(int)
    return(int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = func(a)
    b = func(b)
```

Comment: Ну, в вопросе написано "Нужно получить имя переменной", ваш код очевидно не выводит имена переменных.

Comment: И зря вы встроенный класс `int` своей переменной перекрываете.

Comment: Нет, не то.  Я уже понял что это не реализуемо, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: Реализуемо, почитай про модуль traceback

Comment: Правда это дикий костыль и с регуляркоми помучиться нужно будет